# Always Receiving " ? " from Serial Port in C#

Tags: c#, microcontroller, pic

I'm fetching some bytes sent to a virtual serial port, these bytes come from a PIC microcontroller, I'm using ISIS for simulation, and C# to capture and display those bytes.

In C#, I'm simply opening the virtual serial port and I read the incoming data.

```
SerialPort s = new SerialPort("COM2");
s.Open();
```

And when I click on a button, a method is executed which contains...

```
TextBox1.Text = s.BytesToRead.ToString(); //Displays the number of received Bytes.
TextBox2.Text = s.ReadExisting();
```

The language I'm using for the PIC is Proton.

I'm simply sending out what's inside PORTB.

```
PORTB = 10
HSerOut [PORTB]
```

The result is always an " ? ".

HSerOut["Hello"] -> ?????

Anything that I've missed?

Comment: ? means unprintable char. Check the integer values to make sure you're getting the expected values back. With embedded development binary values are better than text. Also what "Endianness" are you using?

Comment: The odds that your code snippet can work are slim.  You do have to take care of the serial port settings.  Baudrate being an important one that will produce non-ASCII characters when it is set wrong.  Which will produce question marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone receiving weird characters via serial port when communicating with a Microcontroller, you should make sure that you specified the right **Clock or XTAL**, as well as the **SPBRG**, for a `9600 bauds`, use `SPBRG = 23`, and `XTAL = 3.686`